# If Statements in xdotool & bash

Tags: xdotool

I need make a small script in bash using xdotool. And I have problem with if statements. How to write correctly this instruction.

if [xdotool click 1]
then
./myScript.sh
fi

% If I make mouseclick I want to execute bashscript
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash

xdotool click 1 
EXIT_CODE=$?

if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
 ./myScript.sh 
fi
```

exit code 0 - means that you program executed successfully

**UPD:**

```
 xdotool click 1 && ./myScript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in xdotool called **behave** to take an action based on some event like mouse-click But...
The specific mouse-click option is not working (apparently a bug),which is:

```
xdotool search . behave %@ mouse-click exec 'myscript.sh'
```

Although these commands work with **mouse-move** / **mouse-leave** option, which are:

```
xdotool search . behave %@ mouse-move exec 'myscript.sh'
xdotool search . behave %@ mouse-leave exec 'myscript.sh'
```

Another solution would be using **echo -e** like this:

```
echo -e "\e[?1000h"
while read -n 12; do myscript.sh; done
```

Comment: echo -e "\e[?1000h" this only works on clicking on the terminal window, I think can be extended to whole system if using like this:
nohup echo -e "\e[?1000h"